# UIToolbar and Flexable/Fixed bar button items

Tags: iphone, alignment, center, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar, where I want to have one `UIBarButtonItem` centered and have another on the very right. However when I add the button on the right, my centered button gets shifted further to the left (see attached). I can't figure out how to get this resolved without using code (I would like to use interface builder only). Any ideas?

[image: Interface Builder toolbar]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this in just IB, add a fixed bar button item to the very left of the bar that's the exact same width of the 'switch camera' button, followed by a flexible button, your camera icon, another flexible space, and the switch camera.

So it would look like:

```
|--fixed space--||--flexible space--||Camera Button||--flexible space--||switch camera|
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!